# fail to insert required fields in the database

Tags: php, mysql, database, insert

I wasn't clear in my first post. So here it is.

reservation.php

```
<table style="border: 4px;">

    <tr>
                    <!-- Start JQuery Pop-up -->

        <script src="js/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="popup2.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

        <td style="border: 2px solid #000;"><center><img src="images/comp.jpg" height="30" width="50"><br /><b><div id="button"><a href="#" class="pcbutton">PC 05</a></div></b></center>

        </td>


    <!-- Jquery Pop-Up code starts here including the insert query -->
            <?php
                echo '<div id="popupContact">';
                echo '<a id="popupContactClose">x</a>';
                echo '<center><form method = "POST" action="reserve.php">';

                                        mysql_connect("localhost","root","") or die (mysql_error());
                                            mysql_select_db('seat_reservation') or die (mysql_error());

                                            $roomNumber = '400';
                                            $chairNumber = 5;

    //In this part, I try to insert in the database without submitting the form yet.

                                            $insert = mysql_query("INSERT INTO reservation (chair_status, room_id, chair_number) VALUES (0, '$roomNumber', '$chairNumber')");



    //I'm trying to retrieve the inserted data and do the checking.

                                    $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM reservation WHERE room_id = '$roomNumber' AND chair_number = '$chairNumber'");
                                            $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query);

                                            $_SESSION['roomno'] = $row['room_id'];
                                            $_SESSION['chairnum'] = $row['chair_number'];

                                            echo '<h1>Information </h1>';
                                                echo 'Fullname : <input type="text" name="student_name" /><br /><br />';
                                                echo 'Student ID No. : <input type="text" name="stud_id" />';
                                                echo '<br /><br />';
                                                echo '<input type="submit"  value="Submit" />';
                                            echo '</form></center>';
                                        echo '</div>';

                                        echo '<div id="backgroundPopup"></div>';
                                        ?>
                                    <!-- End JQuery Pop-up -->  
                                        <td style="border: 2px solid #000;"><center><img src="images/comp.jpg" height="30" width="50"><br /><div id="button2"><a href="#" class="pcbutton"><b>PC 04</b></a></div></center>
                                        </td>
    //This is another table that's exactly the same from the code above only that this has a different PC number
                                        <?php
                                        echo '<div id="popupContact">';
                                            echo '<a id="popupContactClose">x</a>';
                                            echo '<center><form method = "POST" action="reserve.php">';

                                            mysql_connect("localhost","root","") or die (mysql_error());
                                            mysql_select_db('seat_reservation') or die (mysql_error());

                                            $roomNumber = '400';
                                            $chairNumber = 4;

                                            $insert = mysql_query("INSERT INTO reservation (chair_status, room_id, chair_number) VALUES (0, '$roomNumber', '$chairNumber')");

                                            $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM reservation WHERE room_id = '$roomNumber' AND chair_number = '$chairNumber'");
                                            $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query);

                                            $_SESSION['roomno'] = $row['room_id'];
                                            $_SESSION['chairnum'] = $row['chair_number'];

                                            echo '<h1>Information </h1>';
                                                echo 'Fullname : <input type="text" name="student_name" /><br /><br />';
                                                echo 'Student ID No. : <input type="text" name="stud_id" />';
                                                echo '<br /><br />';
                                                echo '<input type="submit"  value="Submit" />';
                                            echo '</form></center>';
                                        echo '</div>';
                                        echo '<div id="backgroundPopup"></div>';
                                        ?>
```

reserve.php

```
<?php
    session_start();

    $name = $_POST['student_name'];
    $stud_id = $_POST['stud_id'];
    $room_id = $_SESSION['roomno'];
    $chair_num = $_SESSION['chairnum'];

    mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "") or die (mysql_error());
    mysql_select_db('seat_reservation') or die (mysql_error());

    $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM reservation WHERE room_id = '$room_id' AND chair_number = '$chair_num'");
    $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query);

    if($row['chair_status'] == 0)
    {
    $insert = mysql_query("UPDATE reservation SET chair_status = 1, student_name = '$name', stud_id = '$stud_id' WHERE room_id = '$room_id' AND chair_number = '$chair_num'");
        if($insert)
            die ("Seat reserved! <br />Redirecting...<meta http-equiv='refresh' content=2;reservation.php>");
        else
            die ("Try Again! <br />Redirecting...<meta http-equiv='refresh' content=2;reservation.php>");
    }

    else
        die ("Sorry, seat taken! <br />Redirecting...<meta http-equiv='refresh' content=2;reservation.php>");
    ?>
```

Here is a screenshot of the seat reservation:

LINK: [NOTE: change [DOT] to .]
https://fbcdn-sphotos-a.akamaihd[DOT]net/hphotos-ak-ash3/599637_4018881323775_858410964_n.jpg

Here is a screenshot of the pop-up upon clicking a PC:

LINK: [NOTE: change [DOT] to .]
https://fbcdn-sphotos-a.akamaihd[DOT]net/hphotos-ak-ash3/599637_4018881323775_858410964_n.jpg

PROBLEM : Applying the insert code works only in one PC, example PC 05. In the code above, I applied the insert code to PC 05 and PC 04 as a testing only but I want to apply it in all PCs. But applying it only in PC 05 and PC 04 doesn't make it work. In the database, after clicking the submit button, these are the only things inserted (NOTE: room_id is the room number):

LINK: https://fbcdn-sphotos-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-ash3/527207_4018929644983_1759106011_n.jpg

Each student should reserve a seat in this particular classroom. When Student.A clicks on PC 05 as his seat, it should be reserved for him. When Student.B clicks on PC 01 as his seat, again, it should be reserved for him. There are multiple classrooms, I used the JQuery tabs for that. What I wanted to have inside the database is this (NOTE: manual insert only) :

LINK: https://fbcdn-sphotos-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-ash4/376602_4018990806512_1150698954_n.jpg

Your replies will be highly appreciated, thank you in advance!

Comment: Is this your complete code? I don't find `student_name` and `student_id` in any of your SQL statements.

Comment: This is a table right? I expect to see some loops but I don't see any. Would you mind separating the code or maybe just put a comment on the pop-up part and then the code for the table because it's kinda confusing. And also you have commented out lots of code would you mind to remove the code which you don't actually use

Comment: It's probably best to stop answering this one, as the OP has replaced it with [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11685713/failed-to-insert-in-the-database-part-2).

Answer (score 0):

You code is kind of incomplete. Do not use `mysql_query` by itself. Include extra code to catch the error or show the output in case an error occurred while inserting data.

```
$insert = mysql_query("INSERT INTO reservation (chair_status, room_id, chair_number) VALUES (0, 400, 5)");

// I added the below lines to catch how many rows were inserted and if not, what error occured
$inserted_rows = mysql_affected_rows(); 

if ($inserted_rows !=0)
  echo 'Error occurred, through out error'. mysql_error();
```

Answer (score 0):

First off give a name to your submit button so that you can make use of it to check if the form is submitted:

```
if($_POST['name_of_your_submit_button']){
  //mysql insert code here
}
```

And I don't see whether you're actually making use of a user inputted data in your insert query:

```
$insert = mysql_query("INSERT INTO reservation (chair_status, room_id, chair_number) VALUES (0, 400, 5)");
```

Make sure that you are getting some values by using code for debuggin like print_r or var_dump

```
print_r($_POST);
```